# Add one month to date TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-update, date-arithmetic

Could someone help me to add one month to all `exp_date` for my users?
Can I run an SQL query to do that?

Let's suppose my database name is A, and table name is B, and the row containing the date is called `exp_date`. I want to add one month to users that have `exp_date` not nulled.

Is this query correct?

```
SELECT
    exp_date
FROM A.B
WHERE exp_date is NOT NULL
    AND enabled=1
    AND admin_enabled=1
SELECT DATEADD(month,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are looking for `SELECT DATEADD(Month, 1, exp_date) ...`

Answer (score 2):

I cannot understand your query, and you did not tag the RDBMS you are using, but based on the description you gave I think you need a simple `UPDATE` on your table.

This will add 1 month to the `exp_date` of rows that match your the filters of your `WHERE` clause :

In *sqlserver* :

```
UPDATE your_table
SET exp_date = DATEADD(month,1,exp_date)
WHERE 
    exp_date is NOT NULL
    AND enabled = 1
    AND admin_enabled = 1
```

In **mysql** :

```
UPDATE your_table
SET exp_date = ADDDATE(exp_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
WHERE 
    exp_date is NOT NULL
    AND enabled = 1
    AND admin_enabled = 1
```

Comment: I had this erro

Comment: Yes it is Sql server, im trying to run this query in phpmyadmin
but i get this error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1,exp_date) WHERE exp_date is NOT NULL AND enabled = 1 AND admi' at line 2

Comment: you are not using SQL Server @StarlightZ

Comment: This is a typical mysql error. I updated my answer with the syntax for mysql

Comment: im using MariaDB yeah, in your correction
ADDDATE(exp_date, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)

is it going to add only 1 hour ?
Im looking to add 1 month

Comment: Thank you but after executing this:

UPDATE users
SET exp_date = DATEADD(exp_date, INTERVAL 1 month )
WHERE 
    exp_date is NOT NULL
    AND enabled = 1
  
    AND admin_enabled = 1


many fields in exp_date are now NULL !! and others not replaced